# Relationship beween redis client in go and size of pool connections impact latency

Tags: go, redis, go-redis

When I remove cores for a service which connects to redis with go client, the latency between my service to redis is increased. In redis, for each additional core we add 10 connections by default. Meaning, if we remove cores, number of connections decreased too.
Is there a reason why in this case, the latency of a request from my service to redis is increased dramatically?
Both redis and my service reside in aws.

I changed 4 cores to 1 core, sent 2 requests. Latency for one request became 60ms where with 4 cores it 2ms. For two cores, latency for one request is 20ms.

Is it possible it is related to epoll?

Answer (score 0):

There's a cost to managing connections.

The Redis library defaults values based on `GOMAXPROCS` to make it generally scale up and down with your resources. But it's not perfect — no library is going to guess your program's workload accurately.

If you find that you're saturating your connection pool when decreasing available cores, manually configure the behavior to suit your program. The library doesn't multiplex requests over the same connection, so having fewer in the pool means more time spent waiting for a connection to become available.

The settings are here: https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-redis/redis/v8#Options

We're not going to be able to recommend the ideal configuration without profiling your application, but take a look at...

- Minimum idle connections
- Maximum idle connections
- Pool size

If you want to be more accurate, collect CPU and trace profiles for your program to determine what makes sense.

> I changed 4 cores to 1 core, sent 2 requests. Latency for one request became 60ms where with 4 cores it 2ms. For two cores, latency for one request is 20ms.

Without code examples or profile data, this will be hard to answer accurately. There's also network variance, so you'd need to run tests over a longer period of time to find what the real deviation is.

Comment: The story is like that.... I have my own service which sends a request to aws elastic cache (redis). If Im using 4 cores on the machine that sends the request to redis, the latency for this request is 2ms. If Im using one core, the latency is 60ms. I know that whenever a core is added, the amount of connections to redis increased. So im trying to understand if there is a relationship between number of connections to latency

Comment: @TzvikaAvni: As mentioned in the answer, yes — but it also depends on your workload. A single connection can only handle one Redis request at a time. If you have 10 connections in the pool and send 11 requests, one request will need to wait for a free slot. If you decrease CPU but don't change your workload, then your latency will vary. Try setting static connection pool sizes so that it doesn't vary as much, and see if it's more stable.

Comment: I need to send only one request (for a demo Im conducting) and show the letancy. It all began when i removed cores, and noticed the latency change, even for one request. So i wonder why is that

Comment: You're going to need to profile if you want more in-depth answers.